# Obtaining and using the output of a script run remotely by subprocess.check_output

Tags: python, ssh, raspberry-pi, subprocess

I had a hard time trying to find out how to word my problem for the title, and it may not be the best description ever. But below I am explaining my situation in details. I can gladly edit the title if there are any suggestions.

I have two Raspberry Pi at the moment. There will be more than that later. Pi A is the main machine that runs the codes and collects the temperature values. Pi B is just there to run the sensor and collect temperature and humidity values.

I am trying to have every script in Pi A and I am running them remotely on the other machines with ssh.

I am trying a new thing so I will put two simple codes I am working on right now.

First script is af.py. This is stored in Pi A but it will be run in Pi B.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import Adafruit_DHT as dht
h, t = dht.read_retry(dht.DHT22, 4)

print('{0:0.1f} {1:0.1f}'.format(t, h))
```

The output is:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Temp_Codes $ python af.py
26.1 22.7
pi@raspberrypi:~/Temp_Codes $
```

Second one is afvar.py. In this script, I am making Pi B run af.py but the problem is, I want to be able to get the values or the output of the sensor of Pi B directly so that I can continue using them in afvar.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess

#Here I am trying to get the temperature and humidity value inside these two variables t2 and h2

t2, h2 = subprocess.check_output("sshpass -p 'x' ssh pi@192.168.x.x python < /home/pi/tempLog/af.py", shell = True)

#Some other stuff using t2 and h2 .....
#like print "temp is %f and hum is %f" % (t2, h2)
```

At the moment it gives me an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "afvar.py", line 16, in <module>
    t2, h2 = subprocess.check_output("sshpass -p 'x' ssh pi@192.168.x.x python < /home/pi/tempLog/af.py", shell = True)
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Is what I am trying to do possible? I have been checking internet and tried different solutions but this is where I am stuck at the moment.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you edit the question to include the output from af.py, please.

Comment: @MandyShaw I just did, by the way I already accepted the answer of Richard Neumann, because the 4 lines he provided worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subprocess.check_output` returns `bytes`.
What you want to split there, is possibly your output `'{0:0.1f} {1:0.1f}'.format(t, h)`

So, you first must decode the `bytes` to `str` (and possibly strip it from trailing newline) and then split it.

```
output = subprocess.check_output("sshpass -p 'x' ssh pi@192.168.x.x python < /home/pi/tempLog/af.py", shell = True)
output = output.decode().strip()
t2, h2 = output.split()
```

And since you probably want the temperature and humidity as floats, finally parse them:

```
t2, h2 = float(t2), float(h2)
```

Comment: t2, h2 = output.split()
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split'
I had an error like this and after removing the whole decode and strip line, it works perfectly.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that error. Which python version are you using?

Comment: I think there was a paranthesis missing, I added the line again and it works fine with strip too as well. I must have messed up something before but I tried again because as you said it had to work, and it does. Thanks!